# Getting NamespacePrefix as null while running run_tests task with cumulusci

Tags: apex, ci, cumulusci, devopscenter

I am trying to run apex test with CumulusCI, I am running on Unmanaged code(Scratch orgs)
I have set my name space in cumulusci.yml

```
    minimum_cumulusci_version: '3.1.2'
project:
    name: AmpImpact
    package:
        name:  Project_Name
        namespace: My_Namespace
        api_version: '45.0'
    source_format: sfdx
```

Here is my command and output

```
C:\Testing>cci task run run_tests --org dev
[09/28/23 14:40:10] Getting org info from Salesforce CLI for test@example.com
[09/28/23 14:40:28] Beginning task: RunApexTests
                    As user: test@example.com
                    In org: OrgID

                    Running query: SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = null AND (Name LIKE '%_TEST%')
[09/28/23 14:40:29] Found 0 test classes
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed, I had to define namespace in config file(cumulusci.yml)

```
run_tests:
        options:
            managed: true
            namespace: My_namespace
```